# Transformation does not complete until element is inspected in browser

Tags: css

I'm trying to do something like what [pure-css](http://purecss.io/) has with their menu opening button when the user resizes the window to a small width: making spans rotate from horizontal lines into a cross. [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5nZ6/2/)

HTML

```
<div class="navigation">
    <a href="#"><span></span></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.navigation a > span,
.navigation a > span::before,
.navigation a > span::after {
    width: 30px;
    height: 5px;
    transition: all 0.8s;
    background-color: gray;
}

.navigation a > span::before, .navigation a > span::after {
    content: " ";
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.navigation a > span::after {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.navigation a.selected > span {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(1px);
}
.navigation a.selected > span::before {
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(20px, -1px);
}
.navigation a.selected > span::after {
    display: none;
}
```

The weird thing is that the 'X' shape doesn't form properly--until I do `right click -> inspect element`. Then it snaps into shape. Closing the inspection window also triggers this. [Changing the translate](http://jsfiddle.net/y5nZ6/4/) values seemed to fix it, however. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Consider including the pseudo-elements within the `a` box instead of the `span`. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5nZ6/5/) (needs some polishing).